# Is python faster than c++ for http requests?

Tags: python, c++, performance

I have program that is written in `python3.6` and now I wanted to re-write it in `c++` to make it faster. Before doing so, I decided to make a small test to get a inference on how much speed will I gain. The program makes a lot of http request so I decided to test for http request speed. But I was really surprised by the results because python was faster c++ in each request by the average of `~50ms`(sometimes `~100ms`and sometimes `~10ms`) and I didn't understand why.

here is my c++ code:

```
#include "swish/swish.h"
#include <chrono>


int main() {

  swish::Client httpclient = swish::Client();
  std::chrono::milliseconds since = std::chrono::duration_cast< std::chrono::milliseconds >(std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch());
  std::pair<swish::Response<swish::ResponseHeaderBuffer>, swish::StatusCode> resp = httpclient.Get("https://api.btcturk.com/api/v2/ticker");
  std::chrono::milliseconds now = std::chrono::duration_cast< std::chrono::milliseconds >(std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch());
  std::cout << now.count() - since.count() << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

I am using this `swish http client` library(which is just curl wrapper. Here is the library [repo](https://github.com/lamarrr/swish)) to make the request and compiling it with the command `clang++ testcpp.cpp -std=c++17 -o test -lcurl -O3`.

And here is my Python code:

```
import time
import requests

current_milli_time = lambda: int(round(time.time() * 1000))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    since = current_milli_time()
    res = requests.get('https://api.btcturk.com/api/v2/ticker')
    now = current_milli_time()
    print(now - since)
```

Is it because most of those milliseconds because of waiting for response so it is completely network related? but python is faster each time. I tried 20~30 times with different interval. Or is it because python code for this library is really optimized??

Comment: When dealing with any kind of I/O (especially networked I/O) then the actual I/O is by a far wide margin what's going to be slow. The code invoking the I/O is one or more magnitudes quicker no matter what language you're using. Instead think about what you're going to do with the data you fetch, and what language and API's you're most comfortable with. In the end, programmer time is often more expensive than computer run-time, especially if the program run-time is counted in seconds rather than hours.

Comment: Under the hood, the CPython standard interpretor is written in C language. So a Python script cannot be faster than the equivalent C (or C++) code. But as soon as additional libraries are involved they can matter. Here your tests let think that the Python request library is more optimized (or does less things...) than the C++ swish one. An interesting point is whether they wait for full reception of the response for the server. Python standard urllib.request library does not and returns as soon as the headers are available. So you may be comparing different things.

Comment: Python will never be faster than C++, only if you write code by a different logic though you don't think so. And, anyway, you should consider using coroutine to improve the concurrency, at least multi-threading is much better too.

Comment: I suggest, before attempting rewriting to other language your code, to answer question: is my code fast *enough*?

Comment: @SergeBallesta yes. This is what I was thinking that it is because of the library. That is the way I linked the repo. So if I implement the request in directly in sockets, cpp will be faster than python in this case?

Comment: Remember what I said about programmer time being more expensive. If you write a program in language A and it takes 40 hours to write and test, compared to writing it in language B and it takes 16 hours to write and test, which is "best"? Especially when considering that the wast majority of the run time of such a simple program will be spent doing I/O and not actually running your code.

Comment: I seldom sent a request without donwloading the full response... Before making a partial conclusion, build a a more complete test: send the request and read the response. But as this is IO bound, I am amazed that you find very different times: most of the time should be spent in the IO part...

Comment: @SergeBallesta yea this is probably because my internet connection isn't so stable lol. As you said since most of time spent in IO part I wasn't expecting so much difference as well. was expecting cpp would be ```~10ms```faster or something.

Comment: This is way too network bound for it to matter language wise.

Comment: Actually, you are testing nothing comparable. There are 2 different languages, 2 different http libraries (maybe different configurations), real world network latency and a blackboxed webserver.

Comment: For a program that makes lots of network requests, you'll be far better off refactoring your python so it can efficiently parallelize them, e.g. by using aiohttp or some other coroutine library. The cpu time being spent actually sending the http request will be on the order of 1 microsecond, even for the python. It's nowhere near milliseconds.

Comment: @JosephIreland yeap I guess you are right. All the difference here is because of the network latency. I guess I will continue with python because there won't be any valuable difference between them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The difference may be because Python has a very optimized way of page requesting, and the `swish` lib/code you are using hasn't.

The network time may be the same (in fact, it *should* be the same), but you really can't know (unless you developed `swish` lib) what that library is doing.
Asking for a web page in `c++` can be done in several ways and no one can be compared unless *you* write the code for both.
I would say that your method (calling `swish`) is not optimal (but is useful in *all* cases) and Python is designed for optimal "request and wait response."
So in this case, Python has the advantage of having thousands users reporting feedback that allows developers to make it optimized.
Swish may not have so many users, may don't have so much feedback and it isn't so optimized as Python (which calls `c` after all.)

If someone has doubts, there are methods to speed up things like [TCP_NODELAY](https://www.extrahop.com/company/blog/2016/tcp-nodelay-nagle-quickack-best-practices/) that can make a difference. Or just the timeouts in the `select` call.

When talking about *network* the language is not the bottleneck, it is the network. So if you aren't satisfied with your lib performance you should change the *library* not the language.